# select class in oop mysqli and php 5

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, php-5.2

Hello this sound easy but something seems to be wrong here,

```
include_once('class.DBconnnection.php');//connects to DB and works fine

class execute extends db
{

private $sqlString;
private $selected;
private $querySelected;

public function select($sqlString)
{
$connection=$this->getConnection();
$querySelected=$connection->query($sqlString);
if($querySelected->num_rows>0){
$this->Fetch();
}
else{
    echo'No Data Available';
    }   
}   

public function Fetch(){
return $querySelected->fetch_array();

}

}
```

on implimenting the above class

```
 try{

$connect=db::getInstance();
$conn=$connect->getConnection();
$execute=new execute();
$execute->select('select * from users limit 5');
while($execute->Fetch()){
    echo $row['username'].'<br/>';
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

on running i recieve the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\PHP5_Testing\classes\class.execute.php on line 20`

can anyone help me to fix this problem?  when i used procedural mysqli it worked fine but the problem is now with oop mysqli

Comment: to set a class property you have to use `$this->querySelected`

Comment: this is because in `return $querySelected->fetch_array();` `$querySelected` is not a object, its undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

when you use OOP , you must follow the rules!

some problem that i see in your codes , here :

change

```
public function Fetch(){
return $querySelected->fetch_array();

}
```

into :

```
public function Fetch(){
return $this->querySelected->fetch_array();

}
```

and

`$querySelected=$connection->query($sqlString);`

into

`$this->querySelected=$connection->query($sqlString);`

hope this fix your problem.

Comment: inbefore the author is going to say it doesnt work, thats because he's using an undefined var `$row` in his `try{}catch{}`!

Comment: @Neat , you right , but , all of his code have problem! . he don't follow the rules. when he try to `$execute->Fetch()` (before $row...) he face the error

Comment: Can confirm that it is a mess :)

Comment: Perfect i think you have shade some light, dont worry about the code, i was merely used to procedural programming